# Preventing a user from exiting full screen mode to window mode in Electron?

Tags: electron, window, fullscreen, chromium, devtools

I'm working on a desktop app that needs to have all of its windows always in full screen, I don't want the user to be able to exit to window mode. I already searched for it but didn't find anything, any ideas?
Also, can I prevent the user from opening DevTools and that sort of stuff (things coming from chromium and electron by default)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use **kiosk** mode for you main window, and also disable the DevTools.

Please refer to the [new BrowserWindow()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) documentation:

> `options` Object (optional)
>
> > `kiosk` Boolean (optional) - Whether the window is in kiosk mode. Default is `false`.
> >
> > `webPreferences` Object (optional) - Settings of web page's features.
> >
> > > `devTools` Boolean (optional) - Whether to enable DevTools. If it is set to `false`, can not use `BrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` to open DevTools. Default is `true`.

Adding these settings should work, you may want to give it a try:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow
(
    {
        // [...]
        kiosk: true,
        webPreferences:
        {
            // [...]
            devTools: false
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: As this is correct it should be pointed out: there is no 100% way to prevent users from using devTools or exit Kiosk Mode. As electron is not compiled, the user always has access to the sources (even when using ASAR packaging) and can change those Parameters if he knows a little bit about the electron Framework.

Comment: This is a correct and helpful answer for anyone looking to prevent the user from exiting fullscreen by pressing the escape or esc key.